# Why can't I add a shared_ptr<Derived> to a map<key_type,shared_ptr<Base>> in this code?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'd like to add a `shared_ptr<derived>` to a map with `shared_ptr<base>` values (as below http://ideone.com/hd68yc) but it fails (we reach `EXIT_FAILURE`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class base{
    public:
        base(const int& s = 1):setting{s}{};
        int setting;
};
class derived : public base{
    public:
        derived(const int& s):setting{s}{};
        int setting;
};

int main() {
    map<string,shared_ptr<base>> m_s;
    m_s.insert(make_pair("Name",make_shared<derived>(4)));
    // None of these worked either...
    //m_s.emplace("Name",make_shared<derived>(4));
    //m_s["Name"] = make_shared<derived>(4);

    if(4 == m_s.at("Name")->setting){
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }else{
        cout << "setting is " << m_s.at("Name")->setting << " when 4 expected";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize base class member in constructor initialization list, but you can call proper base class constructor:

```
class derived : public base{
    public:
        derived(const int& s):base{s}{};
};
```

Your naive "fix" to put member `setting` into derive class does not fix the issue, but hides it, allow code to compile, but breaking the logic.

Answer (score -1):

For a start, the derived class contains an extra `setting` member.  Getting rid of that revealed that I can't use the `derived(const int& s):setting{s}{};` ctor syntax since it refers to a `setting` member that is inherited.

In the end, using the following fixed my problem:

```
class correct_derived : public base{
    public:
        correct_derived(const int& s){
            setting = s;
        }
};
```

Comment: This probably isn't the most interesting question and answer but I'd spent so much time making an MVCE that I thought I might as well get something out of it!

Comment: You probably should pass correct value to base constructor instead of using default: `correct_derived(const int& s) : base(s) { }`

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks.  In the actual code `derived` is a google mock for another class derived from `base` and so I think I was trying to keep the test code and the unit-under-test separate, originally.

Answer (score -1):

```
m_s.insert(make_pair("Name",make_shared<derived>(4)));

if(4 == m_s.at("Name")->setting) {
```

As far as I can tell you store a Pointer in a map and then compare it to an int (4). You would have to de-reference the stored shared pointer to get its value which you then can compare to '4'. That might be the reason you end up at EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: I agree but the code is kind of an artificial example, I'm using pointers because the values in the map (in the real code) have virtual functions.

Comment: Why OP needs a pointer is irrelevant to the question, he may have reasons that are not visible at MCVE.